# How to read json request body array object?

Tags: json, database, file, parsing, azure-functions

I am sending data in a post request as follow:

```
{
    "HospitalId": "Hospital-0232",
    "DataSliceTimestamp": "2020.08.10",
    "HourQuarter": "00:01",
    "Data": [
        {"country":"US","state":"MS","county":"bolivar","lat":32.354668,"lng":-89.398528,"type":"ICU","measure":"1000HAB","beds":0.241539,"population":33121,"year":2014,"source":"khn","source_url":"https://khn.org/news/as-coronavirus-spreads-widely-millions-of-older-americans-live-in-counties-with-no-icu-beds/"},
        {"country":"US","state":"MS","county":"bolivar","lat":32.354668,"lng":-89.398528,"type":"ICU","measure":"1000HAB","beds":0.241539,"population":33121,"year":2015,"source":"khn","source_url":"https://khn.org/news/as-coronavirus-spreads-widely-millions-of-older-americans-live-in-counties-with-no-icu-beds/"},
        {"country":"US","state":"MS","county":"bolivar","lat":32.354668,"lng":-89.398528,"type":"ICU","measure":"1000HAB","beds":0.241539,"population":33121,"year":2016,"source":"khn","source_url":"https://khn.org/news/as-coronavirus-spreads-widely-millions-of-older-americans-live-in-counties-with-no-icu-beds/"},
        {"country":"US","state":"MS","county":"bolivar","lat":32.354668,"lng":-89.398528,"type":"ICU","measure":"1000HAB","beds":0.241539,"population":33121,"year":2017,"source":"khn","source_url":"https://khn.org/news/as-coronavirus-spreads-widely-millions-of-older-americans-live-in-counties-with-no-icu-beds/"},
        {"country":"US","state":"MS","county":"bolivar","lat":32.354668,"lng":-89.398528,"type":"ICU","measure":"1000HAB","beds":0.241539,"population":33121,"year":2018,"source":"khn","source_url":"https://khn.org/news/as-coronavirus-spreads-widely-millions-of-older-americans-live-in-counties-with-no-icu-beds/"}
        ]
}
```

And for reading the body I am doing it like this:

```
public class RequestBody
    {
        public string HospitalId { get; set; }
        public string DataSliceTimestamp { get; set; }
        public string HourQuarter { get; set; }
        public string[] Data { get; set; }
    }

string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
RequestBody data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RequestBody>(requestBody);
```

But I get error:

**Newtonsoft.Json: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: [. Path 'Data', line 5, position 13.**

Something is wrong while reading array data, please guide.

Comment: well your Data array is not just a string but another JSON object. Thus you cannot just parse it into strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using dynamic type and by pulling out data field from the request body.

```
// Reading body
string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();

// Parse through the request body string and make it in appropriate format.
dynamic RequestBody_data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
var Data = RequestBody_data["Data"].ToString();
```

Through this I was able to get the data field string and then I can split it with "}," to get all the rows. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to strongly type your JSON input to an object array not a string.

Here's an example of what the object could look like:

```
public class Datum
{

    [JsonProperty("country")]
    public string country { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("state")]
    public string state { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("county")]
    public string county { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("lat")]
    public double lat { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("lng")]
    public double lng { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("measure")]
    public string measure { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("beds")]
    public double beds { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("population")]
    public int population { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("year")]
    public int year { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("source")]
    public string source { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("source_url")]
    public string source_url { get; set; }
}

public class RequestBody
{

    [JsonProperty("HospitalId")]
    public string HospitalId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("DataSliceTimestamp")]
    public string DataSliceTimestamp { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("HourQuarter")]
    public string HourQuarter { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Data")]
    public IList<Datum> Data { get; set; }
}
```

You can then deserialize it like you're already doing:

`RequestBody data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RequestBody>(requestBody);`